# Error installing prettytable on ubuntu with pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, prettytable

I just installed pip, installed a few packages np. I tried this

```
pip install prettytable
Collecting prettytable
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f424837d6e0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement prettytable (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for prettytable
```

How do I install prettytable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `PyOpenSSL`. Either your `OpenSSL` is too old or too new. Try upgrading or downgrading `OpenSSL` and `PyOpenSSL`.

Comment: Odd, this is from a fresh digital ocean server. I uninstalled & reinstalled pyopenssl and it works

Answer (score 0):

*Reinstalling pyopenssl worked for me:*

```
pip uninstall pyopenssl
pip install pyopenssl
```